# How do i solve these 2 NP complete problems?

Tags: algorithms, np-complete

A1, A2, A3 ⊂ A in pairs of 2 they have NO common spot. Their union is A and they have same sum.
How can i see this is NP complete .

Second Problem.
A = {a1, . . . , an}
How do i see if a, b, c, d ∈ A different between them exists so a + b = c + d?

Comment: in the second i want to see if it is  ∈ P

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [basic tutorial and quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and review the [Meta Read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and enhance your question to provide your motivation/attempts.